# Adding Crosswalk Fingerprint Extension in Android Studio

Tags: android, fingerprint, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I have a Crosswalk project that I have built in Android Studio. I want to add the fingerprint extension I got here:

https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-samples/tree/master/fingerprint

I was somehow able to add the fingerprint extension when I build using adb, but I don't know how thru Android Studio. I tried to search and search but haven't found any clue, I've tried several options but none worked. Any idea, anyone? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, you can list down the options that you have tried and the problems you found.

Comment: First I tried to add as mentioned in the link. However, my current project structure is not built from ADT, but from Android Studio. I do not know how to add the extension to my existing project in Android Studio. I tried to re-build it in a new ADT project but now I can't make it run properly --plus i'm taking too long a time since everytime I build using "adb" command, i am downloading the latest version of crosswalk from the server which takes too much time.